# Excel file Powerview worksheet not displaying in Application on VMware

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, vmware, citrix

Excel file PowerView worksheet not displaying in Application on VMware, Citrix (Not FAT-PC)

> Only worksheet with PowerView Sheet not display in Excel file

**Brief Info:**

When imported in to specific Application, only the sheets with PowerView are not displayed.

It does not occur in FAT-PC (with Win8.1,Win10), but it occurs with our VDI on both VMware and Citrix.

When we switch to the worksheet with the PowerView object – issue exists.

I can try opening same Excel file from outside Application in my FAT-PC and PowerView object will show.

So far I have tried and checked the PowerView Add-Ins and they are in place.

**Conclusion :** Power View Work sheet works in FAT-PC but not in VDI environment.

Can anyone help me on fixing this...

Comment: Which operating systems do you have on the PC and the VM? Which Excel versions are used? (Power View not available in all Office versions.)

Comment: Both are Win 10 Enterprise Editions and Office 2013 Professional Plus.

Comment: The two installations are not identical. Try [this setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2758433/power-view-sheet-is-not-displayed-in-a-workbook-when-you-open-the-workbook-in-excel-2013).

Comment: @harrymc,will try it and let you know.Thank you for response.

Comment: Hi @harrymc,I did try the option and it did not fix the issue.I still see same issue.Thank you.